# Where to Save Auth Token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis

I have one issue, where I would need some inputs.
In my current application, using Node,Express I have a auth token which is generated by third party post login. I need to save this token on Node layer, as I cannot expose this token on client side.

Is there a better way to save this token on Node layer for each user specific once user gets logged in into the system and invalidate if user logout.

Please note that, there is no authentication done on node layer, it all verifies on some third party API's and that API generates a token.

So my question:

1. How I can save this token on node level.
2. Is there any way available by which I can save token for each user,Currently I am thinking to use Redis as it is just key value pair.
3. If I compare Mongo Vs Redis, which will be a better option?
4. Is there any other way around to solve such scenarios?
5. For example If I will save this on client cookie, how I can make
   this token more secured, so that client cannot read this token.

Comment: A lot of your questions relate to whether or not you need persistent storage.

Comment: Yes, moreover I am looking for persistent storage.

Comment: Then you need to use a database.  Mongo would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer since I do not know whether there is a secure approach to save a token on a cookie. I think that using Redis database is the way to go for its greater performance compared to MongoDb since you would be storing key value pairs as you stated.